# How to make an image into a rich formatted document?

Tags: pdf, ocr, scanning, pictures

So I have a magazine (with couple of pages) in hands and I want to have a resulting file which will keep the whole diagram and image intact, but still allow me to search / find and select text in it.

[This PDF](http://www.cpsc.gov/CPSCPUB/PUBS/516.pdf) is a small example of a result I wish to have. Even the title is selectable! It does seems to have been created for PDF rather than scanned, but you get the idea.

The result file doesn't need to be PDF, although I doubt there is any better format for this. The document needs to be a file (for offline reading) and as cross-platform compatible as possible.

Is there *any*<sub>(simple)</sub> solution to this? If not, how could I at least do the OCR's work manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: @Cawas reports that [PDF-Exchange viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) accomplished the task successfully, performing OCR on a PDF and making it searchable.

For the needs that you listed, PDF is probably the simplest and most cross-platform. Another, slightly more obscure alternative is the DJVU format, but unlike PDF there significantly less support for them, especially in terms of OCR.

There are a [number of free Optical Character Recognition](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/top-5-free-ocr-software-tools-to-convert-your-images-into-text-nb/) software that are available and are easy to use. However, if you are looking for a very simple solution, any PDF document that you upload into Google Drive will [automatically have OCR performed on it](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/176692?hl=en). There are limitations on this, but it should work for short documents.

Comment: I have tried google drive in the past and today. It couldn't process a 3 mb PDF with 2 pages, very simple one. Also, on all my previous trials, it would read the text INTO text and not in the PDF as my example at all.

Comment: Apologies, PDF-XChange Viewer supports what I believe you are looking for, performing OCR on a PDF and making it searchable.

Comment: That sounds amazing! I'll be trying it along the next days.

Comment: You really should edit your answer... PDF-XChange Viewer did it for me. I just couldn't find a way to fix it when the OCR goes wrong, but it's perfect otherwise!

Comment: Glad to hear! Added it to the top.